# Automatically log off idle Windows 7 console sessions

Tags: windows-7

We have a number of shared computers that users never seem to log out of.  Am I correct that there is no built in functionality to automatically log off console sessions after an idle timeout?  I've seen two suggestions: a logoff screensaver, and a scheduled task with an idle trigger.  Will the idle trigger work if only the session is idle, but the computer is in use with a different session?  Is there a better way to go about this?  Thanks,

Comment: http://www.intelliadmin.com/?p=4439 or http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;en-us;314999&

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any info about idle trigger, anyway, you should be able to check sessions via:

```
qwinsta /server:$remoteIP
```

and kill them via

```
rwinsta $sessionid /server:$remoteIP
```

Whit a little scripting and a little check on connection state , you should be able to obtain what you need. Not sure if this can work on w7 too.

Comment: Strange, I get permission denied on remote hosts even with domain admin.

Comment: Give a check using "local-machine" admin! 

Sorry I cant' give you any more precise advice; 
last time i used this was an emergency a couple year ago so I'm not fully aware of syntax and requisites to make this work.

Comment: Not really what I need anyway.  I'm looking for an automated solution.  I'm surprised there's not a GPO for this...